# How to extract a PDF from an SWF player on a web page?

Tags: c#, pdf, flash

There is a book on this page (http://img.docin.com/players/DocinViewer.swf?productId=463932528), and it is inside a swf player. Previously there was a software which can extract all pages in the swf player and store them as a pdf file.

So there should be 3 steps:

1. Find the file source inside the swf player
2. Extract all pages from the swf player.
3. Save them as a whole pdf file.

How might one accomplish this?

Comment: This might point you to the direction where the pdf is loaded from http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/ and/or http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfdotnet/

Comment: @JPHellemons, thx, the second link seems helpful. Do you have any code examples?

Comment: Might want to mention image might be considered NSFW for some work environments though it looked like a medical image of some kind :)

Comment: @Kit what's the NSFW? Any idea about the solution?

Comment: An anatomical diagram. Probably not all that worrisome for most people in most cases, but a bit surprising when you're sitting in a bunch of open cubes. No biggie... see my answer though.

Comment: @JPHellemons I just tried the SwfDotNet library, it is completely out of date. It can only support up to swf version 7. But I need version 9 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer, but perhaps someone can expand. It seems to me that using these two references, you could search for the PDF in the stream you get back in the SWF to identify the SWF header, and structure, and the PDF header and footer and then reconstitute the PDF directly from the stream:

- http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf
- [Structure of a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88582/structure-of-a-pdf-file)

Alternatively maybe an existing tool will do the trick:

- http://download.cnet.com/SWF-Printer-Pro/3000-10743_4-10740922.html

Or update the open source project below, mentioned by a commenter to the level you need, using the references for the newer SWF and PDF formats:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfdotnet/

Comment: it seems that it's about the python rather than C#.