# Parsing PDF file using Apache PDFBox to get outlines

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Now I can use the PDFBox to extract the outlines from PDF, but some PDF can get the outlines, others can't.

Every PDF has outlines and when I open a pdf use pdf read tool, I can click an outline to a certain page.

[image: PDF can get outlines]
[image: PDF can't get outlines]

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
        PDDocumentOutline outline = document.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
        getOutlines(document, outline, "");
        document.close();
    } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void getOutlines(PDDocument document, PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException{
    PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
    while (current != null) {
        PDPage currentPage = current.findDestinationPage(document);
        Integer pageNumber = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().indexOf(currentPage) + 1;
        System.out.println(current.getTitle() + "-------->" + pageNumber);
        getOutlines(document, current, indentation);
        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your code works for some files and not for others. Thus, it would be helpful if you shared an example file for which it does not work.

Comment: "Every PDF has outlines" - no.

Comment: @mkl [the PDF have outlines but can parse it](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LgLPXJAi-e6lRaylvw6Rqna1Kcj7yHmB) and I want to know the structure of a PDF file from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88582/structure-of-a-pdf-file)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I means the PDFs I want to parse have outlines.

Comment: Your link requires individual permission.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you sign in your account to view and download the pdf

Comment: That file does not have outlines.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr [try this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LgLPXJAi-e6lRaylvw6Rqna1Kcj7yHmB/view?usp=sharing) when I open the PDF I can click outline to a certain page(in the PDF page `Iv`)

Comment: That is the same file. It does not have outlines. "Outlines" is that thingie with text on the left in Adobe Reader that is sometimes visible and sometimes must be clicked to be visible. Your file has a table of contents on page 8 (shown as "IV" on the page). That is not an outline as in your screenshot. That's just a bunch of link annotations.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr does it has a method to get these `link annotations` just like the outlines?

Comment: Try the `PrintURLs.java` example from the source code download. Although this is about external links, you can adjust it for internal links.

Comment: I can only confirm @Tilman's analysis. And just a word of warning, it usually is much more difficult to retrieve correct structured information from TOCs in the page contents than it is for actual outlines. As you try to retrieve such data from many documents, be ready for some incorrect extractions and add a feature to your app for manual corrections of the extracted data.